# How to use MEF with WPF

Tags: wpf, mef, layer

Is there a way to create a product (Software) divided in modules?
What I mean is for example create an application using WPF that is divided in 3 modules (in the future they may be more) Main Module, Module 1, Module 2
Each module could be a standalone solution. Each of them with presentation, Business and Data access layers.

From the Main Module when a button is clicked, it will call any other module for example module 1 but the UI of the module should be seen like if it were from the main Module.
I have manage to use MEF to separate project building but I don now how to use MEF with WPF

Any Starting point or suggestion?

[image]

Comment: MEF+Prism is what you are looking for. It's a bit long to explain in one answer, but I'm pretty sure there are enough topics on this on SO and sample applications on the net to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Putting your business and data access layers in a MEF module is fairly straightforward and accomplished as you would for any other project, the trick with WPF is adding the view resources. That can be done by putting them in a ResourceDictionary decorated with the Export attribute and merged into the global dictionary, as shown in the answer to "[How to provide XAML resources from MEF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530670/how-to-provide-xaml-resources-from-mef-components)".