# How can I pass a UserControl from a Plugin to my main window using MVVM?

Tags: c#, plugins, mvvm, view, user-controls

I have a plugin based application where I am discovering plugins using Mono.Addin.  Each plugin has its own View and ViewModel and I am not sure the best method to pass the View down to the MainView.  At the moment my MainView is binding to an object type on my MainViewModel, but this requires me to have UI specific logic in my plugin ViewModel.  I am not entirely comfortable doing this but cant think of a better way.

My MainViewModel has this

```
public object Content
```

and my PluginViewModel does this

```
this.MainViewModel.Content = ViewLocator.Current.ResolveView(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MVVM then the usual way of creating a view from a view model is via data templating, and in order for that to work both the view and data template need to be merged into the application's global ResourceDirectory. There's [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530670/how-to-provide-xaml-resources-from-mef-components) that shows to do that with the MEF plugin architecture but it shouldn't be too difficult to adapt to others.